# Grep for lines that starts with " followed by 10 digits ",""

Tags: grep

e.g.
Find line "1437421130",""
but not "1437421130","92729392"

Cant figure out how to handle double quotes. ( I am an idiot when it comes to grep )

I tried

```
echo "1437421130","" | grep '"\d{10}",""'
echo "1437421130","" | grep '"[0-9]{10}",""'
```

Comment: This seems to work for me: `"\d{10}",""$`.  Test it here: https://www.online-utility.org/text/grep.jsp

Comment: @ChrisStrickland most `grep` implementations do not support `\d`, see [Why does my regular expression work in X but not in Y?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/119905/109046) for details

Comment: @klind can you add the code you tried?

Comment: if \d isn't available, then you should be able to use [0-9] in its place

Comment: I also think you can add -P to enable \d

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did this on centos.  Used single quotes to avoid the double quote escaping.  -E to allow the {10}

[image]

Comment: ah, so looks like what I was missing is the ' in the echo statement and the -E :)